# The name doesn't exist in namespace. Ошибка с присоединением Grid.Resources

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Не совсем понимаю, почему не получается подключить класс к Grid.Resources.

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows.Data;    
namespace WeirdShit
{
    public class Bool2String : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            bool what = (bool)value;
            if (what)
                return Properties.Settings.Default.FilledHeart;
            else
                return Properties.Settings.Default.EmptyHeart;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value.ToString().Contains(Properties.Settings.Default.EmptyHeart))
                return value;
            else
                return true;
        }
    }

    public class Bool2StringTooltip : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            bool what = (bool)value;
            if (what)
                return Properties.Settings.Default.Markedfavorite;
            else
                return Properties.Settings.Default.Markfavorite;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value.ToString().Contains(Properties.Settings.Default.Markfavorite))
                return value;
            else
                return true;
        }
    }

    public class PathToBaseDirectory : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
           string currentDirrectory = System.Environment.CurrentDirectory;
           if(currentDirrectory.EndsWith("\\bin\\Debug"))
           {
                int index = currentDirrectory.IndexOf("\\bin\\Debug");
                currentDirrectory = currentDirrectory.Substring(0, index);
           }
            return currentDirrectory + value.ToString();

        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return "";
        }
    }
}
```

Подключение:

```
<Grid.Resources>
            <local:Bool2String x:Key="star"></local:Bool2String>
</Grid.Resources>
```

студия говорит, *local:Bool2String* отсутствует.
Док-во, что все есть:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Текст ошибки:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Очистите и пересоберите проект. Если не поможет, то дайте скрин окна ошибок и полное содержимое файла `MyConverter.cs` (с using и всем всем всем).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ исправил

Comment: `xmlns:local` покажите, возможно вы не правильно его прописали.

Comment: `xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WeirdShit"` @ヒミコ

Comment: Смотрите. Студия довольно криво дружит с XAML, всякими стилями и прочим. Она часто не видит какой либо класс до тех пор, пока не запустить проект/не пересобрать его/не очистить/не перезапустить студию. Также XAML "собирается" в последнюю очередь и если у вас есть хоть где то ошибка в коде, то до тех пор, пока вы не уберете те ошибки - студия не увидит конверторы. Так что вопросы у меня пока те же - это точно все ошибки (попробуйте удалить пока из ресурсов конверторы и запустите проект)? И Вы точно пересобрали проект как положено?

Comment: Нажмите `Ctrl+Shift+B`, после этого ошибка должна пропасть.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ есть еще куча ошибок, которые потом исправлю. я понял вас, спасибо

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте ПКМ по проекту->добавить->существующий элемент->в открывшемся диалоге выберите Bool2String->открыть