# WPF xaml не видит то, что "должен" видеть

Tags: c#, wpf, .net

Окно не видит мою VM

```
<Window x:Class="MIlitaryProject.Views.MainWindow.BaseWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:Views="clr-namespace:MIlitaryProject.Views.Pages"
    xmlns:ViewModels="clr-namespace:MIlitaryProject.ViewModels"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Military Project" Height="450" Width="800">

<Window.Resources>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:StartMenuVM}">
        <Views:StartMenuV/>
    </DataTemplate>

</Window.Resources>

<ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentVM}"/>
```

На DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:StartMenuVM}"/> ошибка. Код StartMenuVM:

```
class StartMenuVM : BaseVM
{
    private RootVM _rootVM;
    public StartMenuVM(RootVM rootVM)
    {
        _rootVM = rootVM;
    }
}
```

Подключённые библиотеки:

```
using MIlitaryProject.ViewModels.Base;
using MIlitaryProject.Commands;
```

И структура проекта: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Пробовал пересобрать - без результата (раньше помогало)
Что не так? 
Код ошибки:
Ошибка  XDG0008 Имя "StartMenuVM" не существует в пространстве имен "clr-namespace:MIlitaryProject.ViewModels". MIlitaryProject BaseWindow.xaml 13
Окно ошибок: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Покажите полностью окно ошибок

Comment: Это предупреждение дизайнера, а не ошибка компиляции. Вроде бы чинится чисткой кэша студии: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35780402/1988244 - не уверен, актуально ли для новой версии

Comment: @EvgeniyZ добавил

Comment: А `StartMenuVM` точно имеет `namespace MIlitaryProject.ViewModels`? Если да, то чистите кэш, перезапускайте студию, пересобирайте.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Почистил кэш. Пересобрал. Ошибка осталась + 
Ошибка CS0103 Имя "InitializeComponent" не существует в текущем контексте

Comment: А как вы пересобрали, если у вас ошибки? Исправляйте `InitializeComponent` ошибку, тогда все будет работать. Она у вас скорей всего из за того, что в `.cs` и в `.xaml` файле не совпадают `namespace`. Я [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1039651/the-name-doesnt-exist-in-namespace-%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bc-grid-resources#comment1772848_1039651) оставлю вам на всякий...